# GridLayout in ScrolledForm not showing scrollBar

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have components in a View and adding them in a `ScrolledForm`. But as soon as I use `GridLayout`, it is not showing the scrollbars any of the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `GridData.widthHint` parameter to some relatively small value like 100. This will force the layout to not get too wide. Make sure to also set it to fill horizontally.

This should be all that's necessary if your layout doesn't have any controls that increase their height as width is constrained (like wrapped label). If you do, you will notice that your vertical scrollbars have too much slack in them. Reply here and I will give you the rest of the solution.

Comment: I tried form.reflow(true); in the end of execution of code and it worked.

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution for the problem I am facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette

Comment: @Konstantin komissarchik I am having same problem but can be reolve as with you two mention here